# Beautifulsoup python get date and author of a page

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to receive the date and name from the html code of the page, but my code doesn't work. I'm trying to extract from this part of code. With this URL I should receive: my mood and 10 июл 2016, but I get an error.

I am using `type="text/javascript"` as the search phrase because this part of page source begin with: `<script type="text/javascript">` (this part is much bigger than what I inserted, but I need only these two elements, author and date)

HTML part of code from which I am extracting:

```html
ajax.preload('al_photos.php', {"act":"show","list":"album-68872445_00\/rev","photo":"-68872445_422126739","module":"photos"}, ["album-68872445_00\/rev",7557,3696.000000,[{"id":"-68872445_422205711","base":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/","commcount":0,"commshown":0,"comments":"<div id=\"pv_comments\" class=\"pv_comments wall_module\">\n  <div id=\"pv_comments_header\" onclick=\"Photoview.comments();\" class=\"pv_comments_header unshown\"><\/div>\n  <div id=\"pv_comments_list\" class=\"pv_comments_list  unshown\"><\/div>\n  <div class=\"pv_no_commments_placeholder_wrap\">\n    <div class=\"pv_no_commments_placeholder no_rows unshown\">Будьте первым, кто оставит комментарий к этой фотографии.<\/div>\n    <div class=\"pv_closed_commments_placeholder no_rows \">Возможность комментирования этой фотографии ограничена.<\/div>\n  <\/div>\n<\/div>","reply_form":"","reply_options":[],"date":"<span class=\"rel_date\">10 июл 2016<\/span>","tags":[0],"tagged":[],"album":"<a href=\"\/album-68872445_00\" onclick=\"return nav.go(this, event)\">Фотографии на стене сообщества<\/a>","author":"<a href=\"\/lovely_detka_tytyty\" class=\"group_link\">my mood<\/a>"
```

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import json
url = 'https://vk.com/photo-68872445_422126739?rev=1'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.select('type="text/javascript"')[0]
name = json.loads(data.text)["author"]
date = json.loads(data.text)["date"]
print (name)
print (date)
```

[screenshot of page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3l25.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of what your output would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it will help you because I cannot see your data inside the `script` tag.
But, if your final purpose is to get the date and the author, see the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import json
url = 'https://vk.com/photo-68872445_422126739?rev=1'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

dls = soup.find_all("dl",{'class':'si_row'})
for dl in dls:
    atag = dl.find('a')
    if atag:
        author_link = atag.get('href')
        author_name = atag.get_text()
        print(author_link)
        print(author_name)

span_date = soup.find('span',{'class':'item_date'})
if span_date:
    date = span_date.get_text()
    print(date)
```

**EDIT:**

For the record, your error was probably because your are using `requests` to get the page and the data you are searching are in the ajax response. You can take a look at `selenium` if you want get more data from the script

[Selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: It's working perfectly, but how did you find 'class':'si_row' and 'class':'item_date'?? When I am looking with 'view page source' in chrome I can't find these class. What is it a magic? And how it is working? And why your is not working with another URL like this for example: https://vk.com/wall-68872445_34141. Where did you find these class?

Answer (score 1):

Using selenium to return the date and author

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://vk.com/photo-68872445_422126739'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
item =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".group_link"))).text
item2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.rel_date').text
print(item, item2)
driver.quit()
```